# Grails: Call taglib from g:if tag

Tags: grails, taglib

I have a custom tag lib that returns a Boolean object so that my GSP can decide whether to display a piece of html or not.  I would like to use the g:if tag to check this Boolean's value since I also need to check a few other values (that aren't accesible in the taglib).  However, I don't know how to actually call the taglib from the  tag?

I've tried:

```
<g:if test="${<custom:tag/> && other.boolean}">
```

but that throws errors.

I also tried:

```
<g:if test="<custom:tag/> && ${other.boolean}">
```

but that throws errors too.

Comment: Did you try: `<g:if test="${custom.tag() && other.boolean}">`

Comment: Yup, gives me an error saying that tag cannot be called on a null object.

Comment: @tim_yates way seems correct (maybe trouble with the namespace?), but using a taglib in this way is a little bit weird. Are you sure, you're doing it correct?

Comment: You're right, I had an issue with my namespace (typo).  Once that was fixed, calling the taglib the way tim_yates specified worked great.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How does the taglib look like? Looking at the usage it should be as below:

```
class SomeTagLib {
    static namespace = "custom"
    static returnObjectForTags = ['tag']

    def tag = { attrs, body ->
        //returns an object (can be boolean)
    }
}
```

By default, taglibs would return [StreamCharBuffer](http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/util/StreamCharBuffer.html). If you need an object to be returned, (as in your case to be used as part of conditional statement), I guess you would need `returnObjectFromTags` as shown above. It specifies which tag deviates from default behavior and returns an object instead.

Also, you should be using the taglib as mentioned by Tim:

```
<g:if test="${custom.tag() && other.boolean}"> //should be the appropriate way
```