# prevent encoding of taglib output

Tags: grails, taglib

In my Grails app, I've defined the following tag which outputs a `Map`

```
class DataBindingTagLib {

    static namespace = "bind"

    def domainParamList = { attrs ->

        def params = [:]
        // put stuff in the map
        return params
    }
}
```

When I call this tag and store the result in a variable

```
<g:set var="chartParams" value="${bind.domainParamList([:])}"/>
```

If I inspect the type of this variable, it's a `StreamCharBuffer`. So it seems that the value output by the taglib is automatically being converted to this type. I tried to prevent this by changing the line above to

```
<g:set var="chartParams" value="${raw(bind.domainParamList([:]))}"/>
```

But it made no difference. Is there a way to prevent this from happening such that I can store the `Map` instance returned by the tag in the `chartParams` GSP variable? I'm not sure if this is relevant, but I have the following automatic encodings defined in `Config.groovy`

```
grails {
    views {
        gsp {
            encoding = 'UTF-8'
            htmlcodec = 'xml' // use xml escaping instead of HTML4 escaping
            codecs {
                expression = 'html' // escapes values inside ${}
                scriptlet = 'none' // escapes output from scriptlets in GSPs
                taglib = 'none' // escapes output from taglibs
                staticparts = 'none' // escapes output from static template parts
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21991970/grails-call-taglib-from-gif-tag/21992364#21992364

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to instruct your tag library to return an object as a result, by default tag libraries are expected to modify the output stream.

First, let the tag library know you need this particular method/closure to return an object by using the `returnObjectForTags` static hint. Then, simply modify the method/closure to `return` your object instead of modifying `out`. With these two changes your tag will return an object and you can use it as such.

```
class DataBindingTagLib {

    static namespace = "bind"
    static returnObjectForTags = ['domainParamList']

    def domainParamList = { attrs ->

        def params = [:]
        // put stuff in the map
        return params
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, do you think using taglibs like this is perfectably acceptable, or somewhat frowned upon?

Comment: Perfectly acceptable, some of the core tag libraries do this as well as some within very popular plugins (e.g. Spring Security).

Comment: Good, if anyone complains, I'm going to blame you :)

Comment: Haha, sounds like you would fit right in with my co-workers. Our unoffical policy is to "Blame Josh, then let's move on."

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it didn't fix the problem. I've updated my question to show the code changes I made

Comment: Take note of the `tatic returnObjectForTags = ['domainParamList']` that's very important. Otherwise it will not work (as you have seen).

Comment: Oh, I totally missed that, thanks. Was this introduced recently? I've never seen it before.

Comment: It was introduced between v1.1 and v1.2. So it's been around for a bit.